# How to install rapid ssl certificate in nodejs express application

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have the SSL certificate from the rapid SSL and Rapid SSL issued the certificate to the server.
Now I have 4 files.
CACertificate-INTERMEDIATE-1.cer

```
CACertificate-ROOT-2.cer
PKCS7.p7b
CACertificate-INTERMEDIATE-1.cer
ServerCertificate.cer
```

Then how to configure the server to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to setup HTTPS for you node.js web server.

If you are using plain node.js, then you will have to switch from `http` module to `https` module. Take a look at the docs: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener

If you are using some kind of a framework, you will need to consult its docs.

Usually you need a **server certificate** and a corresponding **private key**. The files that you were provided with look like a certificate chain (root CA cert -> intermediate CA cert -> your server cert). The files name `ServerCertificate.cer` conveys a feeling that it is a **server certificate**. But where is your **private key** file? You should consult certificate issuer to find this out.

Comment: Thanks I lost my private key so it is not working but thanks anymore.

Answer (score 1):

ssl-root-cas module helps to use custom certifcates on your node.js server.

You can inject your custom certificate doing:

```
require('ssl-root-cas').addFile('my-cert.crt');
```

Have a look to this article that explains how to use ssl/tls certifcates on your node.js app:

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ssltls-with-node-js/

Comment: I tried but it says that ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH on chrome

Comment: You need to set the certifcate as valid on your browser if the ssl certifcate has not been validated by a certified trust source. http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/#.WUJPfX7yikA 

https://gaboesquivel.com/blog/2014/nodejs-https-and-ssl-certificate-for-development/

Comment: You are right my private key is lost and it is invalid.